# How to save repo file in centos

Tags: linux, centos, repository

I have a link for the repository file

https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/cloudera-manager.repo?_ga=1.139114810.807939978.1489498435

How can I download it? Which command should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/cloudera-manager.repo?_ga=1.118167936.807939978.1489498435`

This is the way to download repo file. Now it seems very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create server.repo file in following location.

cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

You can copy contains from above URL and save the file. After, you can install a package via yum command.